# Django and Mustache use the same syntax for template

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates, javascript-framework, mustache

I try to smuggle HTML template in the HTML for mustache.js, however
the django template engine remove all the placeholders that should be
output as-is to the front-end

The template is included in HTML in this way:

```
<script type="text/x-mustache-template" data-id="header_user_info">
    <div id="header_user_info">
        <div id="notification">0</div>
        <a href="#">{{username}}</a>
    </div>
</script>
```

and I can get the HTML template by running $(el).html(), and generate
html by using Mustache.to_html(temp, data);

I could put all the template into another static file and serve from
CDN, but then it would be hard to track where the template belongs,
and at least one extra http request.

Comment: @Alasdair See my answer for a better way to do this. The `templatetag` solution is way too verbose.

Comment: you can use verbatim tag in your project. Look at [this link](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16318).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the `{% templatetag %}` templatetag to print out characters that would normally be processed by Django. For example:

```
{% templatetag openvariable %} variable {% templatetag closevariable %}
```

Results in the following in your HTML:

```
{{ variable }}
```

For a full list of arguments see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#templatetag

Comment: Great. Then accept my answer. You should probably accept answers to other questions you've asked, as well.

Comment: Nice one! Had no idea about this tag.

Comment: While this works, surely there must be a better way than replacing each instance of `{{` with `{% templatetag openvariable %}`.

Comment: There is a nice gist for including text without parsing it as django templates: https://gist.github.com/629508. It allows you to wrap sections in {% verbatim %}{{ unrendered }}{% endverbatim %}

Comment: Check out my answer below for a MUCH better way to do this.

Comment: The new verbatim tag is the way to go

Answer (score 49):

You can simply change the tags:

```
Mustache.tags = ['[[', ']]'];
```

Comment: Changing the Mustache tag to deal with a Django issue? Not ideal. In the past there weren't much options, but Django 1.5 now supports the verbatim tag. See answer by @cat below.

Comment: Why is the verbatim tag better?

Comment: Just used this approach to avoid Mustache and Liquid template clashes. Simplest and cleanest solution for me.

Comment: Where should i put this ?

Comment: @cafebabe1991 You want to do this right after the Mustache script has loaded. So if you're using jQuery, you should be able to do `<script>$(function() { Mustache.tags = ...; })</script>` at the bottom/top of your file.

Answer (score 22):

If you use django 1.5 and newer use:

```
  {% verbatim %}
    {{if dying}}Still alive.{{/if}}
  {% endverbatim %}
```

If you are stuck with django 1.2 on appengine extend the django syntax with the verbatim template command like this ...

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

class VerbatimNode(template.Node):

    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text

    def render(self, context):
        return self.text

@register.tag
def verbatim(parser, token):
    text = []
    while 1:
        token = parser.tokens.pop(0)
        if token.contents == 'endverbatim':
            break
        if token.token_type == template.TOKEN_VAR:
            text.append('{{')
        elif token.token_type == template.TOKEN_BLOCK:
            text.append('{%')
        text.append(token.contents)
        if token.token_type == template.TOKEN_VAR:
            text.append('}}')
        elif token.token_type == template.TOKEN_BLOCK:
            text.append('%}')
    return VerbatimNode(''.join(text))
```

In your file (python 2.7, HDR) use:

```
from django.template import Context, Template
import django
django.template.add_to_builtins('utilities.verbatim_template_tag')

html = Template(blob).render(Context(kwdict))
```

In your file (python 2.5) use:

```
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
template.register_template_library('utilities.verbatim_template_tag')
```

Source:
http://bamboobig.blogspot.co.at/2011/09/notebook-using-jquery-templates-in.html

Answer (score 6):

Try to use [django-mustachejs](https://github.com/mjumbewu/django-mustachejs)

```
{% load mustachejs %}
{% mustachejs "main" %}
```

Django-mustachejs will generate the following:

```
<script>Mustache.TEMPLATES=Mustache.TEMPLATES||{};Mustache.TEMPLATES['main']='<<Your template >>';</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue, but using

```
{% templatetag openvariable %} variable {% templatetag closevariable %}
```

is too verbose for me. I've just added a very simple custom template tag:

```
@register.simple_tag
def mtag(tagContent):
    return "{{%s}}" % tagContent
```

So that I can now write:

```
{% mtag "variable" %}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the built-in mustache.js set delimiter tag to change the default tags that mustache uses.

i.e.

```
{{=<% %>=}}
```

now you can do this:

```
<% variable %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, so most of the time my variables are part of a translatable string.

```
{% trans "The ball is {{ color }}" %}
```

You can use the trans templatetag even if you don't offer i18n.